Vacuum expectation of polynomial of bosonic creation and annihilation operators
Let $\hat{a}^\dagger,\hat{a}$ be creation and annihilation operators with commutator
$$
[\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger] = 1.
$$
Let $|0\rangle$ be vacuum state that
$$
\hat{a} |0\rangle=0.
$$
Let $\beta$ be any complex number. Let $m,n,k$ be positive integers. I'm trying to determine
$$
\langle 0 | \hat{a}^m (\beta^* \hat{a}-\beta \hat{a}^\dagger  )^k (\hat{a}^\dagger)^n   | 0\rangle,
$$
but it's too complicated. Is there useful mathematical tools or theorems about this?

Does this answer your question? Ladder operator identity for $\langle n | (a+a^\dagger)^k | m \rangle$
